# Improve performance for repetitive Mongo database access task

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, performance, meteor

I'm building a chat bot (using `MeteorJS/NodeJS`) which interacts with about **2,000** active users everyday. I know the exact number of people who chat with the bot everyday because I store the users active information in a `MongoDB` collection called `ActiveReports`.

This is a scenario in my app: if a user A chat with the bot **100 times** (= 100 messages) in a day, these steps will be executed:

```
- receive message from users   
- check if this user is marked as 'active' today ?  // high cost
- if yes => don't do anything   
- if no => mark this user as 'active' for today
```

As you can see, step 2 is executed for every messages. This step is technically equivalent to **accessing the ActiveReports collection, find the one with timestamp = today, user = user A**. Since the `ActiveReports` collection has a lot of documents (about 100,000 documents), this is a fairly heavy task. This negatively affects the app's performance.

**NOTE 1:** This is the `ActiveReports` collection schema:

```
SimpleSchema({
  // _id must be set `type` as String and `optional` as true
  //  to avoid ObjectId(_id) after insert in to database
  _id: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,  // Note: date is always the timestamp of the start of the current day, so 1AM timestamp and 9PM timestamp will be changed to 0AM timestamp (before the insert)
  },
  userId: {
    type: String,
  },
});
```

And this is how I indexed this collection:

```
ActiveReports._ensureIndex({ date: 1, userId: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

**NOTE 2:** A user is **active** in a day means he interacts with the bot at least 1 time (e.g send a message to the bot) that day.

Any ideas how I can improve this ? Please tell me if you need further information. Thank you.

Comment: It would help to see your schema and how you defined your indexes.  Also, how do you determine "active"?  Code always helps...

Comment: Thanks @JimBaldwin, I added more information to the post (how I define the collection schema + index and what 'active' means).

Comment: Are you running something like `date: {$gte: start, $lt: end }` to find the ActiveReport for the day?

Comment: Hi @Ivan, I updated the schema description in NOTE 1 to describe how I store date values. Basically I convert the timestamps to the start of the day.

Answer (score 3):

Add a field `last_active_date` to a User schema and update it every time you get a message. If the date matches today, you are done. If it's not, you need to update the field and add a record to `ActiveReports` collection.

Actually, it seems to me that you are trying to use Mongo here in a way you would use a relational database. I mean, that there is no need in `ActiveReports` if you just want to mark a user as active.

If you are trying to build some sort of report for showing app usage per user per day, you can do it in the background. You can have a job that will run once a day (actually, if you have users in different time zones and you want to tolerate their time, you may want to run it few times a day). This job will query the `User` collection and add records to `ActiveReports` for each user it finds where `last_active_date` is `current_date`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're building a stateless server application the minimum you need to do is pull the user's record to check active.

You might consider having  have a daemon task process the ActiveReports and update user dates in the background.  That way you only process those records once and the user info is ready to go.  Also, that process can have state so it can be more optimal that updating every user for every record.